# Why does count(*) restrict my search to 1 row

Tags: mysql

Using the employees database (https://github.com/datacharmer/test_db) I have (as an example) the following statement:

```
select first_name, count(*) from employees;
```

Now this would give the following output:

```
first_name  |  count(*)   
Georgie     |  300024
```

While this statement:

```
select first_name, (select count(*) from employees) from employees;
```

would give the following output:

```
first_name  |  select count(*) ...   
Georgi      |  300024
Bezalel     |  300024
Parto       |  300024 
etc...      |  300024
```

To clarify my Question: I don't understand why the first statement restricts my search query to 1 row (only Georgi is showing up) while the last statement (with the subquery) shows all names and hence doesn't restrict my search query to 1 row like the first one.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @BenM I don't understand why the very first statement restricts my search query to 1 row (only Georgi is showing up) while the very last statement (with the subquery) show all names and hence doesn't restrict my search query to 1 row like the first one.

Comment: `select first_name, count(*) from employees;` is really an under-specified query which MySQL interprets something like `select a_random(first_name), count(*) from employees;` Most other RDBMS's bail out on this type of query.

Comment: In addition to @JoachimIsaksson comment, The last query is giving you results for each name since it is selecting again and again for each first name, the content that is inside this 'correlated query' .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your first Query:**

`Count()` is an aggregate function, it counts all rows in a dataset (or a group). That is why you get only 1 row because you have only one set here.

**Your second Query:**

You are doing exactly the same thing (refer to first query) but now you're doing it in `subquery` so it runs for every row and it is again `Count(*)` so it returns the same value.

**Solution:**

You need to use the `Group By` to make groups in your data by `first_name`. And then `Count` the rows in every group:

```
Select first_name, count(first_name) 
From employee
Group by first_name
```

It will give you count for all `first_name` in your dataset.

Comment: That's it, thanks! Also sorry if my question wasn't very clear.

Answer (score 2):

The way `COUNT` works in combination with the `GROUP BY` clause can be a little bit confusing the first time you encounter it. I will try to explain how it behaves in each of the examples you provided.

> select first_name, count(*) from employees;

`COUNT` is an [aggregate function](http://www.sqlcourse2.com/agg_functions.html). Such function will perform it's computation on **each** set of rows  (called **group**) being returned by the `SELECT` statement. You can create multiple groups using the `GROUP BY` clause, but since you don't use it in this query the whole dataset will act as one group. Therefore, the `COUNT` function will count the entire number of rows in your table.

One way to put it is that the number of rows in the final result will be equal to the number of groups.

> select first_name, count(*) from employees group by first_name;

Let's assume that your table contains 6 rows in total, from which three have the first_name field equal to **Foo** and the other three to **Bar**. You will end up having two groups, and the `COUNT` function will count the number of rows in each group. Therefore, the result will have two rows, looking like this:

```
-------------------------
| first_name | COUNT(*) |
-------------------------
| Foo        | 3        |
| Bar        | 3        |
-------------------------
```

> select first_name, (select count(*) from employees) from employees;

In this example, having a the second query in your `SELECT` statement is no different than having a constant. Consider the following query:

> select first_name, 5 from employees;

Your result will have two columns. The second column will always contain 5. When you do the second query as part of you `SELECT` statement, the result of that query will be used in exactly the same way.

I hope this makes it at least a little bit clearer.

Answer (score -1):

No.  It's correct. It counts all. Use group-by to count distinct of name.

```
Select first_name,  count(*) from employee
Group by first_name
```

Or use proper count with distinct

```
Select first_name,  count(distinct first_name) from employee
```

This one counts distinct values on given column name.